# Django HTML max length of imported text

Tags: html, django

I am working on a project in django and am trying to minimize the amount of text displayed on a page showing entries for various topics. The idea is to just give the first 200 characters and then they can open it in another page to read the whole entry.

Below is the code for the html page...

```
{% extends "AARs/base.html" %}

{% block header %}
  <h2>{{ topic }}</h2>
{% endblock header %}

{% block content %}
  <p>
    <a href="{% url 'AARs:new_action' topic.id %}">Add new action</a>
  </p>

  {% for action in actions %}
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <small>
          {{ action.date_added|date:'M d, Y H:i' }}
        </small>
        <small>  <a href="{% url 'AARs:edit_action' action.id %}">Read or Edit Action</a></small>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <small>
          <input type="text" name="action" maxlength="10">
            {{ action.text|linebreaks }}
        </small>
      </div>
    </div>
  {% empty %}
    No actions have been added yet.
  {% endfor %}

{% endblock content %}
```

I have tried inserting maxlength="200" in various places that I thought might work, but to no avail.

Obviously, I am a newbie. Am excited to be doing stuff beyond my level. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a template tag

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatechars

```
{{ action.text|truncatechars:200 }}
```

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks. Seems I was searching for an html solution to a django issue.