# html in django page to limit length of text

Tags: html, django

I am building a tool in django. It allows myself, and others, to make entries (imagine a journal) for various 'topics'. When the topic is clicked a page opens ('topic' page) that shows the entries. I am trying to limit the length of that text to 200 characters such that if someone wants to see the whole entry, they need to click on that entry to open it up to its specific page.

I have tried putting a maxlength="200" in a few different places. But nothing worked. The only thing I did that kind of worked was to create a 'textarea' with a maxlength="200" but that was visually odd and unappealing. I know there has to be some way to limit the length in the existing code, without creating a new area and putting the entry in there.

Below is the code for the 'topic.html' page. I am thinking that should be enough. If you need the views.py or models.py, let me know.

```
{% extends "AARs/base.html" %}

{% block header %}
  <h2>{{ topic }}</h2>
{% endblock header %}

{% block content %}
  <p>
    <a href="{% url 'AARs:new_action' topic.id %}">Add new action</a>
  </p>

  {% for action in actions %}
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <small>
          {{ action.date_added|date:'M d, Y H:i' }}
        </small>
        <small>  <a href="{% url 'AARs:edit_action' action.id %}">Read or Edit Action</a></small>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <small>
          <input type="text" name="action" maxlength="10">
            {{ action.text|linebreaks }}
        </small>
      </div>
    </div>
  {% empty %}
    No actions have been added yet.
  {% endfor %}

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django HTML max length of imported text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55153699/django-html-max-length-of-imported-text)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be looking for the [truncation filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#truncatechars) in Django's template language:

- truncatechars
- truncatechars_html
- truncatewords
- truncatewords_html

As an example, quoting from the docs:

```
{{ value|truncatewords:2 }}
```

If `value` is "Joel is a slug", the output will be "Joel is …".

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks. Seems I was searching for an html solution to a django issue.